# prevent webview from loading favicon

Tags: android, apache, webview

How is possible to force web-view not to try to download the favicon?
It makes many requests and my pages don't load correctly! (in Android 5.1 and 5 +)

My website page is in PHP and server is Apache.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1321878/how-to-prevent-favicon-ico-requests

Comment: Thankyou @Robert  . but it is a html. i want to use it for all my pages . in some php pages i cant use that tag! so i need to force webview to stop that request

Comment: You should extend your question and elaborate more why you want to do it respectively what you trying to achieve. Usually a missing favicon doesn't harm anybody. You could even add an empty favicon are deny access to the file.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Disable Android WebView/WebViewClient Initiated favicon.ico Request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34886582/disable-android-webview-webviewclient-initiated-favicon-ico-request)