# What is "isForMainFrame" request in Android WebViewClient property meaning?

Tags: android, google-chrome, web, webview, chromium

What is [`isForMainFrame`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebResourceRequest.html#isForMainFrame()) meaning (android-21)?

> whether the request was made for the main frame. Will be false for iframes, for example.

is not clear, since for the log below it returns `false` for main frame requests.

Is it the same as [`isMainFrame`](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/external/chromium_org/+/android-4.4_r1.0.1/android_webview/java/src/org/chromium/android_webview/AwContents.java#236) in android-19?

For "google.com" (which is immediately redirected to "google.ru" according to my locale) i'm getting the following log for android-19:

```
3068-3088 D/IoThreadClientInvocationHandler: isMainFrame=true for http://www.google.com/
3068-3088 D/IoThreadClientInvocationHandler: isMainFrame=false for https://ssl.gstatic.com/gb/images/qi2_00ed8ca1.png
3068-3088 D/IoThreadClientInvocationHandler: isMainFrame=false for https://www.google.ru/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_160x56dp.png
3068-3088 D/IoThreadClientInvocationHandler: isMainFrame=false for https://www.google.ru/images/nav_logo242_hr.png
3068-3088 D/IoThreadClientInvocationHandler: isMainFrame=false for https://www.gstatic.com/og/_/js/k=og.mob.en_US.p8Smm-clGwA.O/rt=j/m=md/exm=mih,mab,meb/d=1/ed=1/rs=AA2YrTsvrSisM1LDBap6j28t9xwsb4oJBg
3068-3088 D/IoThreadClientInvocationHandler: isMainFrame=false for https://www.google.ru/xjs/_/js/k=xjs.qs.ru.WqzjCT34eOw.O/m=sx,c,sb_mob,bct,cdos,elog,hsm,jsa,mbsf,r,qsm,d,csi/am=AIG2TGBhALBBYgn5FBACKAE/rt=j/d=1/t=zcms/rs=ACT90oHeC71MlDyUp6g3gXk23kbF4ygyvw
3068-3088 D/IoThreadClientInvocationHandler: isMainFrame=false for https://www.google.ru/xjs/_/js/k=xjs.qs.ru.WqzjCT34eOw.O/m=sy7,sy13,em2,sy12,aa,abd,sy55,sy54,sy53,sy57,em10,async,sy280,sy320,sy319,dvl,sy425,foot,ipv6,shm/am=AIG2TGBhALBBYgn5FBACKAE/rt=j/d=0/t=zcms/rs=ACT90oHeC71MlDyUp6g3gXk23kbF4ygyvw
3068-3088 D/IoThreadClientInvocationHandler: isMainFrame=false for https://www.google.ru/images/branding/product/ico/googleg_lodp.ico
3068-3088 D/IoThreadClientInvocationHandler: isMainFrame=false for https://www.google.ru/images/nav_logo242.png
3068-3088 D/IoThreadClientInvocationHandler: isMainFrame=false for https://www.google.ru/gen_204?v=3&s=mobilewebhp&atyp=csi&ei=7kT-V-OSNcOfsgHEgL2gAw&imc=1&imn=1&imp=1&adh=&xjs=init.251.13.sb_mob.199.dvl.23.c.8.async.6.jsa.5&ima=1&rt=xjsls.161,prt.164,iml.716,dcl.574,xjses.1086,xjsee.1535,xjs.1536,ol.1873,aft.716,wsrt.1937,cst.728,dnst.1,rqst.219,rspt.36,sslt.721,rqstt.1645,unt.862,cstt.916,dit.2155
3068-3088 D/IoThreadClientInvocationHandler: isMainFrame=false for https://www.gstatic.com/og/_/ss/k=og.mob.-1m1er1bg50qhy.L.W.O/m=md/excm=mih,mab,meb/d=1/ed=1/rs=AA2YrTuS2ZHRm9kj5jyes52ZN2R47G8RQQ
```

for android-21 i can see:

```
1725-1851 D/IoThreadClientInvocationHandler: 21: true for http://www.google.com/
1725-1851 D/IoThreadClientInvocationHandler: 21: false for https://www.google.ru/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_160x56dp.png
1725-1851 D/IoThreadClientInvocationHandler: 21: false for https://ssl.gstatic.com/gb/images/qi2_00ed8ca1.png
1725-1851 D/IoThreadClientInvocationHandler: 21: false for https://www.google.ru/images/nav_logo242_hr.png
1725-1851 D/IoThreadClientInvocationHandler: 21: false for https://www.gstatic.com/og/_/js/k=og.mob.en_US.p8Smm-clGwA.O/rt=j/m=md/exm=mih,mab,meb/d=1/ed=1/rs=AA2YrTsvrSisM1LDBap6j28t9xwsb4oJBg
1725-1851 D/IoThreadClientInvocationHandler: 21: false for https://www.google.ru/xjs/_/js/k=xjs.qs.ru.WqzjCT34eOw.O/m=sx,c,sb_mob,bct,cdos,elog,hsm,jsa,mbsf,r,qsm,d,csi/am=AIG2ZGBhALBBYgn5FBACKAE/rt=j/d=1/t=zcms/rs=ACT90oGqh459Mg-Bg7N2WXgWV78Tvd2J1A
1725-1851 D/IoThreadClientInvocationHandler: 21: false for https://www.google.ru/xjs/_/js/k=xjs.qs.ru.WqzjCT34eOw.O/m=sy7,sy13,em2,sy12,aa,abd,sy55,sy54,sy53,sy57,em10,async,sy280,sy320,sy319,dvl,sy425,foot,ipv6,shm,udlg/am=AIG2ZGBhALBBYgn5FBACKAE/rt=j/d=0/t=zcms/rs=ACT90oGqh459Mg-Bg7N2WXgWV78Tvd2J1A
1725-1851 D/IoThreadClientInvocationHandler: 21: false for https://www.google.ru/images/nav_logo242.png
1725-1851 D/IoThreadClientInvocationHandler: 21: false for https://www.google.ru/gen_204?v=3&s=mobilewebhp&atyp=csi&ei=Qkb-V4-7AoOisAGdzq24Bg&imc=1&imn=1&imp=1&adh=&xjs=init.181.13.sb_mob.151.c.12.mbsf.4.jsa.4.async.4&conn=unknown&ima=1&rt=xjsls.146,prt.155,iml.4995,dcl.4791,xjses.5597,xjsee.6069,xjs.6070,ol.6264,aft.4995,wsrt.1045,cst.155,dnst.0,rqst.127,rspt.9,sslt.147,rqstt.837,unt.671,cstt.681,dit.1305
1725-1851 D/IoThreadClientInvocationHandler: 21: false for https://www.gstatic.com/og/_/ss/k=og.mob.-1m1er1bg50qhy.L.W.O/m=md/excm=mih,mab,meb/d=1/ed=1/rs=AA2YrTuS2ZHRm9kj5jyes52ZN2R47G8RQQ
1725-1851 D/IoThreadClientInvocationHandler: 21: false for https://www.google.ru/images/branding/product/1x/gsa_shadowed_144dp.png
```

I expected to see `true` for all the resources since it's the resources from the main (and single) frame at "google.ru". Am i wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `isForMainFrame` method is actually inherited from WebKit. For instance, here is in the [Apple docs](https://developer.apple.com/reference/webkit/wknavigationresponse/1459482-isformainframe)

Thus, here MainFrame refers to the WebKit concept, which is the root WebFrame.

> Behind the scenes, WebFrame objects encapsulate the content contained in a single frame element. A hierarchy of WebFrame objects is used to model an entire webpage where the root is called the main frame

You can find more on that in [the docs](https://developer.apple.com/reference/webkit/webview)

By this definition, only the initial request is for the "main frame", the rest are requests for the children WebFrames.

Comment: so it will be exactly 1 invocation for webpage url with `isForMainFrame=true` and all other requests `isForMainFrame=false` (images, css, scripts, etc) ?

Comment: @4ntoine as I understand from the WebKit docs and source, yes

Comment: is there any possibility to detect frame (main/iframe) of the element to be loaded?